# sessionStorage registration

Tags: javascript, session-storage

I got few problems on a script

I can't understand why my timer still keep on going while "minutes" and "secondes" === 0
Second thing, if i'm reloading the page my timer left.

```
let get_sec = sessionStorage.getItem('sec_storage');
let get_min = sessionStorage.getItem('min_storage');

if (!get_sec && !get_min){
    //Sessionstorage vide
    secondes = 10;
    minutes = 0;
}
let interval = setInterval(function () {
    secondes--;
    sessionStorage.setItem('sec_storage', get_sec);
    sessionStorage.setItem('min_storage', get_min);
    $('#count-timer').text('Expiration in : ' + minutes + ' minutes ' + secondes + ' secondes ');
    if (secondes === 0) {
        minutes--;
        secondes = 59;
    }
    if(minutes <= 0 && secondes <= 0){
        clearInterval(interval);
        sessionStorage.removeItem('sec_storage');
        sessionStorage.removeItem('min_storage');
        $('#count-timer').text('Sorry, reservation expired');
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: You code never seems to use/update get_sec and get_min....

Comment: How i'm supposed to do ? Sessionstorage is totally new for me ...

Comment: Well you use the variable `get_sec` for reading sessions storage and proceed to use the variable `secondes`. Somewhere I would expect to see 
`secondes = parseInt(get_sec)` or probably `var secondes = get_sec ?
 parseInt(get_sec)` : yourDefaultValue;`

Answer (score 1):

In these blocks

```
if (secondes === 0) {
    minutes--;
    secondes = 59;
}
if(minutes <= 0 && secondes <= 0){
    clearInterval(interval);
    sessionStorage.removeItem('sec_storage');
    sessionStorage.removeItem('min_storage');
    $('#count-timer').text('Sorry, reservation expired');
}
```

If the `secondes` value is === 0, you change it to 59. therefore, in your last `if`, `secondes` is never lower nor equal to 0 and `clearInterval(interval);` is never called

Add this verification in your first `if` block

```
if ((minutes > 0) && (secondes === 0)) {
    minutes--;
    secondes = 59;
}
```